# Ошибка Spring: AbstractApplicationContext#getBean(Class<T> requiredType) выдает null

Tags: java, spring

Нужна ваша помощь и подсказка. Дело, думаю, в какой-то мелочи, которую я в упор не вижу. Ковыряю потихоньку Spring по лекции Евгения Борисова (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BmBr5diz8WA) и столкнулся с такой проблемой (репозиторий с проектом на гитхабе https://github.com/redbeard3/SpringProject/tree/master/src/main) - выполнение кода падает с ошибкой:

```
апр 20, 2019 6:21:16 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [common_beans.xml]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at redbeard.Runner.main(Runner.java:8)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Причем:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("common_beans.xml");
```

отрабатывает нормально, бин из common_beans.xml с id='terminatorQuoter' настраивается, то есть в поле repeat бина terminatorQuoter выставляется нужное значение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка именно в

```
context.getBean(TerminatorQuoter.class).sayQuote();
```

потому что:

```
 context.getBean(TerminatorQuoter.class) выдает null
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, если я убираю все, что связано с аннотацией InjectRandomInt, то есть ее вообще не использую, и в методе sayQuote() просто вывожу сообщение:

```
System.out.println(message);
```

то все работает.
Подскажите, где что упустил. Хотя лекцию несколько раз пересмотрел, тщательно выверил все, что сделал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InjectRandomIntAnnotationBeanPostProcessor в методе postProcessAfterInitialization возвращает null - замените на o. 
А вообще, насколько помню, Евгений как раз хотел показать почему надо вытаскивать бины по интерфейсу, а не по классу. Потому что из BeanPostProcessor класс может вернуться совсем другой, но реализующий тот же интерфейс.

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно, проблема была в том, что postProcessAfterInitialization возвращает null